# Who discovered the largest known $3$-perfect number in $1643$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, math-history, conjectures, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

Multiperfect numbers probably need no introduction. (These numbers are defined in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiply_perfect_number) and [MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MultiperfectNumber.html).)

I need the answer to the following question as additional context for a research article that I am currently writing:

> Who discovered (in the year $1643$) the largest known $3$-perfect number to date?

Here are the six known $3$-perfect numbers, with the last being [discovered](http://math.colgate.edu/%7Eintegers/a6self/a6self.pdf) more than $360$ years ago, in $1643$:
\begin{align*}
120 &= 2^3 \times 3 \times 5, \\
672 &= 2^5 \times 3 \times 7, \\
523776 &= 2^9 \times 3 \times 11 \times 31, \\
459818240 &= 2^8 \times 5 \times 7 \times 19 \times 37 \times 73, \\
1476304896 &= 2^{13} \times 3 \times 11 \times 43 \times 127, \\
51001180160 &= 2^{14} \times 5 \times 7 \times 19 \times 31 \times 151. \\
\end{align*}

Note that $N$ is an odd perfect number if and only if $2N$ is a (necessarily) even $3$-perfect number. (My profuse thanks to [Professor V. M. Misyakov](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/V-Misyakov) for pointing out my mistake in [ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/post/On_Odd_Perfect_Numbers).)

This [link](https://t5k.org/glossary/page.php?sort=MultiplyPerfect) asserts that it was [René Descartes](https://www.mathgenealogy.org/id.php?id=125358) who discovered the following multiperfect numbers:
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\text{index} & \text{smallest}    & \text{name}        &    \text{ found by }         \\
\hline
4            & 30240              & 4-\text{perfect}   & \text{Descartes (1638)}   \\
\hline
5          & 14182439040        &    5-\text{perfect}   & \text{Descartes (1638)}   \\
\hline
\end{array}

Perhaps
\begin{align*}
51001180160 &= 2^{14} \times 5 \times 7 \times 19 \times 31 \times 151
\end{align*}
was also discovered by Descartes in $1643$, judging from the timing.  Did he?

Comment: Your final question sounds very difficult to refute. Is there any rumor or source that mentioned that he did find it?

Comment: I honestly do not know, why is why I had to ask, @Arkady.

Comment: Forgot to mention where I got the information that the largest $3$-perfect number was found in $1638$.  Hold on.

Comment: Adding appropriate context now to the question (lifted from [this paper](http://math.colgate.edu/~integers/a6self/a6self.pdf)).

Comment: Your source says that the last was discovered in 1643.

Comment: Indeed, thank you for pointing that out.  (My apologies for the mix-up.) Editing the question now.

Comment: Dickson's history of number theory puts it at 1643 by Fermat as well: https://www.google.com/books/edition/_/FYWn8XWrAI0C?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA33. The rest of that section may be similarly interesting.

Comment: @Semiclassical: Your [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4698554/who-discovered-the-largest-known-3-perfect-number-in-1638?noredirect=1#comment9943077_4698554) certainly answers my question, and puts things in their proper perspective.  ( Boy, I did not realize that it was a mess, back then!  =( )

Comment: @Semiclassical: Please write that out as an actual answer, so that I may upvote, and then accept.  =)

Comment: One should always consult standard refernces such as Dickson's *History* before posting such questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dickson's [History of the Theory of Numbers - Vol. I (page 36)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/_/FYWn8XWrAI0C?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA36) states that the largest known $3$-perfect number to date ($51001180160 = 2^{14} \times 5 \times 7 \times 19 \times 31 \times 151$)
was discovered by Fermat in the year $1643$.

Thank you to [Semiclassical](https://math.stackexchange.com/u/137524) for pointing this out in a [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4698554/who-discovered-the-largest-known-3-perfect-number-in-1643?noredirect=1#comment9943077_4698554).